# GRE Cumulative addition problem.

Tags: arithmetic

The following problem is quoted from *Manhattan 5lb Book of GRE Practice Problems*, 2016ed.

> **Question**: Molly worked at an amusement park over the summer. Every two weeks she was paid according to the following schedule: at the end of 1st $2$ weeks, she received \$$160$. At the end of each subsequent 2-week period, she received \$$1$, plus an additional amount equal to the sum of all payments she had received in the previous weeks. How much money was Molly paid during the full $10$ weeks of summer?
>
> **Solution**: \$$2575$

I am not sure why Molly received \$ $2575$ at the end of 10 week. To my understanding, she should receive \$ $1288$.

My understanding is the following

```
Weeks        Paid
  2          160
  4          1+160 = 161
  6          1+161+160 = 322
  8          1+322+161+160 = 644
  10         1+644+322+161+160 = 1288
```

Why was additional \$$1287$ paid?

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Check your sum: $1+322+161+160=$?

Comment: Also, the question "How much money was Molly paid during the full 10 weeks of summer?" is different from "How much money was Molly paid in week 10?"

Comment: The third term in the last row should read `322`, not `422`.

Answer (score 1):

The question is how much did Molly earn **in total**, not in the last two-week period. The mysterious 'additional $\$1287$' is simply the sum of all earlier earnings:
$$1287 = 160+161+322+644$$
hence her total earning is
$$160+161+322+644 + 1288 = 2575$$

Comment: @yahoo.com Probably that was paid, because the agreement between Molly and the amusement park stated so. She worked for them, they paid her for the work.

Answer (score 0):

Weeks        Paid

2          160

4          1+160 = 161

6          1+161+160 = 322

8          1+322+161+160 = 644

10         1+644+322+161+160 = 1288

Now 160 + 161 + 322 + 644 + 1288 = ...

Comment: why was additional 1287 paid?

Comment: She earned 1288 in week 10 only, in order to get the total salaries you need to sum up the weekly ones.

Comment: I still don't understand.

Comment: Imagine you work one week and you earn 1 a day. Although you get 1 on sunday you get 7 in total.

Answer (score 0):

I will give a brief explanation

In $2$ weeks she earned $=160$

In the next two weeks she earned $=1+160=161$

In the next two weeks she earned $=1+161+160=322$

In the next two weeks she earned $=1+161+160+322=644$

In the final two weeks she earned $=1+322+161+160+644=1288=>$ Note that $1288$ is the amount she earned in last $2$ weeks

Now we need to add the total amount $=160+161+322++644+1288=2575$